# Android:Is killing of each activity is equivalent to destroying whole app?

Tags: android, android-activity, static

My app contains 2 activities both of them depend on some static objects.I'm curious will android terminate whole app and clean my static fields if both activities are destroyed(for instance when device runs out of mem)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start with a bit of background: What happens when you start an application?
The OS starts a process and assigns it a unique process id and allocates a process table.A process start an instance of DVM(Dalvik VM); Each application runs inside a DVM.
A DVM manages class loading unloading, instance lifecycle, GC etc.

Lifetime of a static variable: A static variable comes into existence when a class is loaded by the JVM and dies when the class is unloaded.

So if you create an android application and initialize a static variable, it will remain in the JVM until one of the following happens:

1. the class is unloaded
2. the JVM shuts down
3. the process dies

Note that the value of the static variable will persist when you switch to a different activity of another application and none of the above three happens. Should any of the above three happen the static will lose its value.

You can test this with a few lines of code:

- print the uninitialized static in onCreate of your activity -> should print null
- initialize the static. print it -> value would be non null
- Hit the back button and go to home screen. Note: Home screen is another activity.
- Launch your activity again -> the static variable will be non-null
- Kill your application process from DDMS(stop button in the devices window).
- Restart your activity -> the static will have null value.

The answer to your question.
yes, if all of your activities are destroyed your application process will be killed.

Credits **Samuh**

Comment: Yeah I noticed that.My question is will android kill application process if all its activities are destroyed?

Comment: yes, if all of your activities are destroyed your application process will be killed.

Comment: yeah, added to my answer. Happy coding.